# Marginnote section alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, marginnote

I have a chapter table of contents inserted as a margin note.

Is there a way to align the margin note and section header? I have tried inserting the margin note definition in the section header as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184771/vertical-alignment-of-marginnote-and-section-heading), but it seems to interfere with the table of contents and the file doesn't compile.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside]{memoir}
% Page layout
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.7cm}{8.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1.7cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setmarginnotes{0.5cm}{\dimexpr(\stockwidth-\textwidth-4.4cm)}{1em}
\checkandfixthelayout
\chapterstyle{bianchi}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\newcommand{\chaptoc}{
    \startcontents[chapters]
    \marginnote{
        {
            \large
            \bfseries
            \sffamily
            OUTLINE
        }
        \vspace{0.5em}
        \hrule
        \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}[1]{}
        \hrule
}}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Example Chapter}

    {\chaptoc\section{Example Section}}

    \lipsum
    \section{Example Section II}
    \lipsum
    \subsection{Example Subsection}
    \lipsum

    {\chaptoc\chapter{Example Chapter}}

    \section{Example Section III}
    \lipsum
    \section{Example Section IV}
    \lipsum
    \subsection{Example Subsection}
    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way with aligned `minipage`s:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside]{memoir}
% Page layout
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.7cm}{8.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1.7cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setmarginnotes{0.5cm}{\dimexpr(\stockwidth-\textwidth-4.4cm)}{1em}
\checkandfixthelayout
\chapterstyle{bianchi}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\newcommand{\chaptoc}{
    \startcontents[chapters]
    \marginnote{
    \begin{minipage}[b,inner sep=0,outer sep=0]{\linewidth}
           { \large
            \bfseries
            \sffamily
             OUTLINE
        }
        \vspace{0.5em}
        \hrule
        \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
        \hrule
        \end{minipage}
}}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Example Chapter}

    {\chaptoc\noindent\begin{minipage}[inner sep=0,outer sep=0]{0.9\linewidth}\section{Example Section}\end{minipage}}

    \lipsum
    \section{Example Section II}
    \lipsum
    \subsection{Example Subsection}
    \lipsum

    {\chaptoc\chapter{Example Chapter}}

    \section{Example Section III}
    \lipsum
    \section{Example Section IV}
    \lipsum
    \subsection{Example Subsection}
    \lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]